# Can I reload a gif image on refresh?

Tags: animation, refresh, gif

I am trying to make a 404 Error Page, with an animated GIF, and the page refreshes to the homepage in 10 seconds. If I refresh the page, the animation does not start over. I have no idea what I can do, I had a look all over the internet and can't figure it out. I don't know anything about php and javascript so hints and clues don't help me unless it is just html or css somehow.
Here is my error page: https://antarctica-ufo.com/errors/error404.htm

And if you believe in UFO's, please make sure you read my story on the homepage ;)

Also, does anyone know of a really good comment box system code that works without ads, even one you can purchase. Now I add the comments I get on the form. haha It does work.

Answer (score 0):

I find an easy way, just to rename the .htm file as .php and use this code instead:

```
<img src="images/countdown.gif?<?php echo date("Ymdgis");?>" />
```

Cheers!